# Tracker dropdown is missing in the Tracking settings (in Movie clip editor)

Tags: interface, tracking

In the tracker settings panel, I can choose options like pattern size and search size, but below the search size, I see: "Tracker:", with no option to choose from. Under that line, I see "Motion model:" with some options to choose.

I'm hoping to get better tracking using "hybrid", but I just can set that option. Any suggestion what happened to it?

Note: using blender 2.68a (2.68.0 r58537) on Win7.

[image: Missing tracker dropdown - highlighter by red arrow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option was [removed in 2.64](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Motion_Tracker#Tracking_Settings):

> First, the old option called Tracker was eliminated. The old Hybrid tracker
>   was doing exactly the same as the SAD tracker, with the exception that
>   it could do more accurate subpixel precision tracking by following the
>   brute-force search with a subpixel refinement. The SAD tracker was
>   also limited in that it only worked on 8-bit images and is unsuitable
>   for 32-bit float images like those used in Mango.
>
> Secondly, the KLT tracker with its pyramid tracking helped tracking
>   blurry footage, but could be quite useless when the background texture
>   was moving in the opposite direction of the feature point. In such
>   cases the Hybrid tracker was much better than KLT, and for this reason
>   the KLT tracker was made obsolete.

In other words, the *SAD* and *KLT* options were replaced with a improved hybrid tracker with new options.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Motion_Tracker#Tracking_Settings):

> The new tracker is a unified algorithm with more options, and
>   specifically some options to make it work exactly the same as the old
>   non-planar Hybrid tracker. The options are:
>
> - **Motion Model** defines which possible motions tracking feature has. Currently supported models are: Location only, Location+Rotation,
>     Location+Scale, Location+Rotation+Scale, Affine and Perspective. This
>     option should be set depending on which motion a particular feature
>     has and it'll make tracking most accurate for such a motion.
>     Perspective is usually used to track a planar feature, but often
>     Affine is a good enough approximation and may have more stable tracks.
> - **Prepass** enables a two pass tracking, where the first pass is a brute force tracking of location only, and the second pass will use
>     tracking of the full motion model refining the first pass. To get
>     behavior that is almost identical to the Hybrid tracker in previous
>     Blender versions, enable Prepass and set the motion model to Location
>     only.
> - **Normalize** means patterns will be normalized by their average intensity while tracking, to make them invariant to illumination
>     changes. An example where this is useful is a scene where a marker
>     moves in the shadow of an actress. Previously it would not be possible
>     to track such a situation, scale adaption would shrink the area to
>     compensate for the change in illumination, losing the track. With
>     "Normalize" turned on, the patch is correctly tracked and scale is
>     maintained.
> - **Correlation** is now a single value for all tracking settings and defines the minimal correlation between a matched pattern and a
>     reference to be considered a successful tracking. If the tracker is
>     giving up too easily, decrease this value, or if the tracker is
>     slipping too much when it should give up sooner, increase this value.

Note that it is possible to simulate the old *Hybrid* tracker with the current method:

> To get behavior that is almost identical to the Hybrid tracker in
>   previous Blender versions, enable Prepass and set the motion model to
>   Location only.

E.g:

[image]